# Failed to execute command: env DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBIAN_PRIORITY=critical apt-get --assume-yes -q update

Tags: ceph

I'm new to Ceph, and I'm trying to install and config a ceph-cluster.
After successfully installing the ceph-cluster I've run into some issues regarding storage and decided to re-install after purging everything and following this guide
https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-a-ceph-cluster-on-ubuntu-16-04/
which went well the first time I've installed this.
But in my second attempt I get this error after running the install command:
`ceph-deploy install ceph-admin ceph-osd1 ceph-osd2 ceph-osd3 mon1`

And this is my output:

```
[ceph_deploy.conf][DEBUG ] found configuration file at: /home/cep/.cephdeploy.conf
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ] Invoked (2.0.1): /usr/local/bin/ceph-deploy install ceph-admin ceph-osd1 ceph-osd2 ceph-osd3 mon1
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ] ceph-deploy options:
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  verbose                       : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  testing                       : None
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  cd_conf                       : <ceph_deploy.conf.cephdeploy.Conf instance at 0x7f11585e0b90>
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  cluster                       : ceph
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  dev_commit                    : None
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  install_mds                   : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  stable                        : None
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  default_release               : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  username                      : None
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  adjust_repos                  : True
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  func                          : <function install at 0x7f115851d9d0>
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  install_mgr                   : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  install_all                   : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  repo                          : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  host                          : ['ceph-admin', 'ceph-osd1', 'ceph-osd2', 'ceph-osd3', 'mon1']
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  install_rgw                   : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  install_tests                 : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  repo_url                      : None
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  ceph_conf                     : None
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  install_osd                   : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  version_kind                  : stable
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  install_common                : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  overwrite_conf                : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  quiet                         : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  dev                           : master
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  nogpgcheck                    : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  local_mirror                  : None
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  release                       : None
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  install_mon                   : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  gpg_url                       : None
[ceph_deploy.install][DEBUG ] Installing stable version mimic on cluster ceph hosts ceph-admin ceph-osd1 ceph-osd2 ceph-osd3 mon1
[ceph_deploy.install][DEBUG ] Detecting platform for host ceph-admin ...
cep@ceph-admin's password: 
[ceph-admin][DEBUG ] connection detected need for sudo
cep@ceph-admin's password: 
[ceph-admin][DEBUG ] connected to host: ceph-admin 
[ceph-admin][DEBUG ] detect platform information from remote host
[ceph-admin][DEBUG ] detect machine type
[ceph_deploy.install][INFO  ] Distro info: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic
[ceph-admin][INFO  ] installing Ceph on ceph-admin
[ceph-admin][INFO  ] Running command: sudo env DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBIAN_PRIORITY=critical apt-get --assume-yes -q update
[ceph-admin][DEBUG ] Hit:1 http://mirrors.service.networklayer.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
[ceph-admin][DEBUG ] Hit:2 http://mirrors.service.networklayer.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
[ceph-admin][DEBUG ] Hit:3 http://mirrors.service.networklayer.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
[ceph-admin][DEBUG ] Hit:4 http://mirrors.service.networklayer.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
[ceph-admin][DEBUG ] Hit:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease
[ceph-admin][DEBUG ] Ign:6 https://artifactory.haifa.ibm.com/artifactory/hrl-site-layer-ubuntu bionic InRelease
[ceph-admin][DEBUG ] Hit:7 https://artifactory.haifa.ibm.com/artifactory/hrl-site-layer-ubuntu bionic Release
[ceph-admin][DEBUG ] Hit:8 http://apt.puppetlabs.com bionic InRelease
[ceph-admin][DEBUG ] Ign:9 https://download.ceph.com/rpm-nautilus/el7 bionic InRelease
[ceph-admin][DEBUG ] Err:10 https://download.ceph.com/rpm-nautilus/el7 bionic Release
[ceph-admin][DEBUG ]   404  Not Found [IP: 158.69.68.124 443]
[ceph-admin][DEBUG ] Ign:12 https://pkg.duosecurity.com/Ubuntu bionic InRelease
[ceph-admin][DEBUG ] Hit:13 https://pkg.duosecurity.com/Ubuntu bionic Release
[ceph-admin][DEBUG ] Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wireguard/wireguard/ubuntu bionic InRelease
[ceph-admin][DEBUG ] Reading package lists...
[ceph-admin][WARNIN] E: The repository 'https://download.ceph.com/rpm-nautilus/el7 bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
[ceph-admin][ERROR ] RuntimeError: command returned non-zero exit status: 100
[ceph_deploy][ERROR ] RuntimeError: Failed to execute command: env DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBIAN_PRIORITY=critical apt-get --assume-yes -q update
```

Already tried to use a different machine as the admin-node and re-install but nothing seems to work, I hope someone here could help :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to sort it out by changing the repository it is downloading from to debian-15.2.4 by installing Ceph like this:

```
ceph-deploy install  ceph-admin ceph-osd1 ceph-osd2 ceph-osd3 mon1 --repo-url=https://download.ceph.com/debian-15.2.4/
```